# Create new column equal to the value of another variable in the row where a third variable is at a minimum

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df <- data.frame(day = rep(1:7, 4),
                 week = rep(1:4, each=7),
                 price = round(runif(28), 2))
```

I would like to create a new column `price_day_1` equal to `price` where the corresponding value for `day` is at a minimum within each week. I had a solution to this a long time ago that I think started with a `group_by` followed by a `mutate` which might have included a `where` function. I would like a solution that does not involve creating a new dataframe, loops, binding columns or rows or anything like that, I am pretty sure there is a neat way to do it inside a single `mutate` (maybe with a preceding `group_by`).

I tried playing around with `mutate` and `group_by` and looking at help section for `where`.

Answer (score 1):

You can index `price` by `first` entry of `day`.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(price_day_1 = price[min(day) == day], .by = week)

   day week price price_day_1
1    1    1  0.67        0.67
2    2    1  0.37        0.67
3    3    1  0.65        0.67
4    4    1  0.21        0.67
5    5    1  0.24        0.67
6    6    1  0.47        0.67
7    7    1  0.49        0.67
8    1    2  0.32        0.32
9    2    2  0.28        0.32
10   3    2  0.48        0.32
11   4    2  0.46        0.32
12   5    2  0.47        0.32
13   6    2  0.06        0.32
14   7    2  0.03        0.32
15   1    3  0.78        0.78
16   2    3  0.74        0.78
17   3    3  0.95        0.78
18   4    3  0.24        0.78
19   5    3  0.68        0.78
20   6    3  0.96        0.78
21   7    3  0.42        0.78
22   1    4  0.62        0.62
23   2    4  0.13        0.62
24   3    4  0.95        0.62
25   4    4  0.09        0.62
26   5    4  0.80        0.62
27   6    4  0.30        0.62
28   7    4  0.00        0.62
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Would you have any idea why the same approach does not appear to work with dates? E.g.:
```
df <- data.frame(day = as.Date('2020-01-01')+0:27 ,
                 price = runif(28)) %>% 
  mutate(week = lubridate::week(day)) %>% 
  group_by(week) %>% 
  mutate(price_day_1 = price[min(day)])
```

Comment: @Brendan To be syntactically correct, I think we should use `price[first(day) == day]`. So in your code it should be `price_day_1 = price[min(day) == day]`. Since your `day` is actual date, indexing by a `min` date doesn't make sense logically. My bad for providing a flawed syntax in the first place.

Comment: If your dataframe is already sorted by `day`, I guess @Peter's solution (now deleted) is simpler `df %>% group_by(week) %>% mutate(price_day1 = first(price))`

Answer (score 1):

Updated following OP's explanation in comments and made more robust by including `arange(day)`.

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(day = rep(1:7, 4),
                 week = rep(1:4, each=7),
                 price = round(runif(28), 2))
df1 <- 
  df |> 
  group_by(week) |> 
  arrange(day) |>
  mutate(price_day1 = first(price))

head(df1, 14)
#> # A tibble: 14 × 4
#> # Groups:   week [2]
#>      day  week price price_day1
#>    <int> <int> <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1     1     1  0.29       0.29
#>  2     2     1  0.79       0.29
#>  3     3     1  0.41       0.29
#>  4     4     1  0.88       0.29
#>  5     5     1  0.94       0.29
#>  6     6     1  0.05       0.29
#>  7     7     1  0.53       0.29
#>  8     1     2  0.89       0.89
#>  9     2     2  0.55       0.89
#> 10     3     2  0.46       0.89
#> 11     4     2  0.96       0.89
#> 12     5     2  0.45       0.89
#> 13     6     2  0.68       0.89
#> 14     7     2  0.57       0.89
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. Not quite. I am looking for `price_day_1` to be equal to the value of `price` where `week`is at a minimum. So in your example the first 7 rows it should be equal to 0.29, then in the next 7 rows it should be equal to 0.89.

Comment: OK have updated the answer rather than deleted so there is a 'dplyr` version.

Comment: Actually this is more or less the same as @benson23 so back to deletion as it does not add anything.

Comment: Resurrected following @benson23's comment!